# Change the component weight dynamically in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Suppose now there are some components inside a JPanel and the layout is arranged using GridBagLayout. Is it possible to change the weight(weightx or weighty)  of the components dynamically (e.g. after pressing a button)? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove and add the component with a new GridBagConstraint. After that call

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Use the method to get current constraints public GridBagConstraints getConstraints(Component comp)

Comment: You should be able to replace the remove and add with `GridBagLayout.setConstraints`.

Comment: & Tom: Both of your solutions are fine. Thank you.