# Changing the constraints of a component in a GridBagLayout after they've been added to the frame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've seen two other posts on *stackoverflow* about this and in both, the solutions use `setConstraints(myComponent, anotherConstraint)` which doesn't even come up as an available method when I try to use it in java.

[want to change an Inset in a gridbag layout dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589139/want-to-change-an-inset-in-a-gridbag-layout-dynamically)

[Change the component weight dynamically in GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920209/change-the-component-weight-dynamically-in-gridbaglayout)

How else could I change the `weightx` of a component after a button press?

The actual problem is that I have two components at the bottom of the screen and I need to set one of the components to be the max width of the screen after a button press.

[image]

Comment: void setConstraints(Component comp, GridBagConstraints constraints) is in the JavaDocs for GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't get `setConstraints()` to work..

Then it seems the code was wrong. From the fact the RHS of the red panel neatly aligns with the LHS of the `Articuno` label I suspect that the grid bag cell containing the red panel does not span more than one column, and currently entirely fills that column.

There could be other reasons, but short a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I won't speculate further.

[image] [image]

Here is a simplified example showing how to do it. Note that it was necessary to call `revalidate()` before the changes could be seen.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class FullWidthToggle {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    FullWidthToggle() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        ui = new JPanel(gbl);
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                160, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), gbc);

        final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Full Width");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        ui.add(checkBox, gbc);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Am I full width?");
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(label, gbc);

        ActionListener actionListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            } else {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            }
            gbl.setConstraints(label, gbc);
            ui.revalidate(); // <- important! 
        };
        checkBox.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            FullWidthToggle o = new FullWidthToggle();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```